# Exibir códigos no front-end sem que sejam executados pelo Edit Post

Tags: html, wordpress

Preciso que meu *front* apresente códigos e scripts sem que eles sejam executados ao criar POSTS. Existe algum plugin para isso? Eu utilizei o `<pre></pre>`, mas ainda assim os códigos HTML são executados.

Vejam na imagem abaixo **no *front***. Existe um quadro verde, pois o HTML foi executado, **não quero que isso aconteça**. E mais abaixo o código JavaScript, que apresenta corretamente como deve ser:

[image]

Comment: Pro HTML, você não foge de ter que escapar os caracteres. Você pode fazer isso manualmente (o que vai ser um porre), ou usar alguma coisa pronta que faça o escape pra você, e aí você cola o resultado no post e manda bala. Outra solução seria usar um filtro do wp pra fazer isso pra você (vou estudar essa opção mais a fundo). Uma terceira maneira, é usar algo como o prism.js http://prismjs.com/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O mais simples é usar um [Custom Field](https://codex.wordpress.org/Custom_Fields) para colar o código e usar um [Shortcode](https://codex.wordpress.org/Shortcode_API) para fazer o display em HTML puro.

**O post ficaria assim**:

[image]

<sup>Pode usar quantos shortcodes quiser, é só colocar um nome único para o *field name*, no meu exemplo `cod-1` (um nome arbitrário).</sup>

**O *Custom Field***:

[image]

**Código do plugin**:
<sup>Sempre verá quem diga *"cole isso no arquivo functions.php do theme"*;

é errado, [**faça seu próprio plugin**](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/72183/12615), não tem problema que tenha 20 linhas.</sup>

```
<?php
/**
 * Plugin Name: (SOpt) Shortcode para código HTML
 * Plugin URI: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/86941/201
 * Version: 1.0
 * Author: brasofilo 
 */

add_shortcode( 'codigo', 'shortcode_sopt_83496' );

function shortcode_sopt_83496( $atts )
{
    global $post;

    // field não definido, não faz nada
    if ( !isset( $atts['field'] ) )
        return '';

    // pega valor do custom field no atributo "field" do shortcode
    $code = get_post_meta( $post->ID, $atts['field'], true );

    // envelopa o código na tag <pre>, estilizar a classe com CSS
    return sprintf(
        '<pre class="codigo-front">%s</pre>', 
        htmlentities( $code, ENT_QUOTES )
    );
}
```

**Resultado**:

<kbd>[image]</kbd>

<sub>*Pode usar um plugin como o [**Advanced Custom Fields**](http://www.advancedcustomfields.com/) para fazer uma interface para os CFs, em vez da default do WP.*</sub>